# Is there an easy way to penalize ML model complexity with hyperopt?

Tags: xgboost, hyperparameters, hyperopt

I want to optimize an `xgboost` model parameter `max_depth` to decrease the loss.

Hyperopt quickly finds a good loss after 10 iterations of around 0.3 and then turns up `max_depth` to my upper bound to get just a little improvement on my loss. After 1000 iterations it comes to an `max_depth` of 18 and a loss of 0.29 although there were models tested with `max_depth` of 3 and a loss of 0.30.

Is there a way to find a less complex parameter settings with closely the same loss? In specific: Is it possible to penalize the objective function, so that the model complexity only increases `max_depth` if there is a significant impact on the loss function?